# Can I change client certificate in the browser without a restart?

Tags: client-certificates, tls1.3, mtls

I am working on using client-side certificates MTLS certificates in FireFox/Chrome and that works fine.

But, is there any way I can get the client certificate selector to open so that I can change the client certificate without having to restart the browser?

For the **edge** **browser** I just discovered that it is possible as described in this blog post:

- [Client Certificates and Logout](https://textslashplain.com/2020/10/19/client-certificates-and-logout/)

So, the question is if this is possible in Chrome/Firefox?